# How to replace single quotes instead of double quotes in array of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of string values with double quotes all i want is convert the array string value with single quotes.

```
Var arr=["abc123","cde345","ijk789"];

var test=[]
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 ans=arr[i].replace(/"/g,"'")
  test.push(ans)
}
```

The test result supposed to be ['abc123','cde345','ijk789']

Comment: That's not how it works, why would you need to change the type of quotes? JavaScript will always save strings with double quotes

Comment: The quotes are just indication that its a string value. So you can either go `'hello' or "hello"` So whether Single quotes or Double quotes, does not matter.

Comment: When i check this value with oracle that wont take the double quotes. That's why I want to convert into single quotes

Comment: How are you passing the Value to oracle? How are you getting the string array?

Comment: do you mean somthing like `"update foo set bar = 'baz' where id = 42"`

Comment: for i.e  db.execute(`select * from tableName where id in (${arr})`,{},outputFormat)

Answer (score 3):

You could map the items with single quotes for a list and join it with comma.

```js
var array = ["abc123", "cde345", "ijk789"],
    list = array.map(s => `'${s}'`).join(', ');

console.log(`select * from tableName where id in (${list})`);
```

Comment: how do we convert double quote [["f"], ["aamer", "babette"]] to single quote [['f'], ['aamer', babette']]

Comment: @RizwanPatel, double quotes are only to show the strings. internal there is no double nor single quoting. please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).