# How to get argv from raw strings

Tags: node.js

I want to get argv from raw string line like the following.

```
const argv = parse('ping -t 197.168.11.1');
// argv == ['ping', '-t', '197.168.11.1']
```

But, split method is not supported double quote strings.
I should be create parser by hands made?

Comment: split method is not supported double quote strings?

Could you please elaborate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51063765/11082661

Comment: split(' ') is split tokens by space. but double quote string contain spaces.